# read more link only when excerpt of content is available in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am working on a homepage which includes post, sometimes the post is only with featured image and no content, and sometime there is post with both featured image and content. i want to show excerpt with the post with a readmore button when there is content available with the post. i have added a read more button but it even shows with the post which don't have any content. how can i show it only when there is excerpt available for content. here is the code for the excerpt div.

```
<div class="entry-excerpt">
            <?php
                    if( strlen( $post -> post_excerpt . $post -> post_content ) > 0 ){
                ?>
                        <div class="excerpt">
                            <?php
                                if( is_user_logged_in () ){
                                    the_excerpt();
                                    echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . __('Continue Reading ', 'cosmotheme') . get_the_title() . '" rel="bookmark">Continue Reading</a>';
                                }else{
                                    $meta = meta::get_meta( $post -> ID  , 'settings' );
                                    if( isset( $meta['safe'] ) ){
                                        if( !meta::logic( $post , 'settings' , 'safe' ) ){
                                            the_excerpt();
                                            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . __('Continue Reading ', 'cosmotheme') . get_the_title() . '" rel="bookmark">Continue Reading</a>';

                                        }
                                    }else{
                                        the_excerpt();
                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the question is solved...
here if anyone want to need it in future.

just add this code in functions.php

```
<?php
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
return '<a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Read the full article...</a>'; } add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser ); ?>
```

The `$more_link_text` sets the link text like "Read More". The second one, `$strip_teaser`, sets whether or not the "more" link should be hidden (TRUE) or displayed (FALSE). The default is FALSE, which shows the link text.

[Source](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More)

Comment: now it is showing the full content of the post in homepage, not the excerpt.

Comment: If you read the source correctly and fully, you'll get the answer to your problem